# jqGrid - unable to display advanced search dialog

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Am loading ~6K rows via php/PDO. Search button appears in nav toolbar but does nothing when clicked.

Includes:

```
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqgrid/4.6.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqgrid/4.6.0/plugins/searchFilter.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/plugins/ui.multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/plugins/ui.multiselect.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqgrid/4.6.0/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" ></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqgrid/4.6.0/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqgrid/4.6.0/plugins/grid.addons.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqgrid/4.6.0/plugins/grid.postext.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqgrid/4.6.0/plugins/grid.setcolumns.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqgrid/4.6.0/plugins/jquery.contextmenu.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqgrid/4.6.0/plugins/jquery.searchFilter.js"></script>
```

Grid is defined as:

```
var grid = $("#list2");

grid.jqGrid({
    url: "loadIssues.php",
    datatype: "json",
    colModel: [

 ...
                    ],
    pager: "#pager2",
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    gridview: true,
    autoencode: true,
    ignoreCase : true,
    loadonce : true,
    width: 800,
    height: "auto",
    shrinkToFit: true,
    search: true,
    jsonReader: {
            repeatitems: false,
            root: "rows"
    },
```

followed by:

```
grid.jqGrid('navGrid','#pager2',{add:false,edit:false,del:false,search:true,refresh:false},
                    {},{},{},  {multipleSearch:true,overlay:false});

grid.searchGrid(  {multipleSearch:true,overlay:false} );
```

Chrome debugger doesn't show any errors.

What step(s) did I miss?

Comment: is that possible to provide a link to an example page?

Comment: Unf no. It's all internal.

Comment: you should **remove** `plugins/searchFilter.css`, `plugins/jquery.searchFilter.js` and other plugins which you don't need. `search: true` option is probably wrong too. The URL `..jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css` is very suspected. Probebly it should be `..jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should **remove** `plugins/searchFilter.css`, `plugins/jquery.searchFilter.js`. It's **old** searing components which are deprecated.
2. The URL `../jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css` is very suspected. Probably it should be `../jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css`.
3. Remove other plugins which you don't need.
4. `search: true` option is probably wrong too, but it's not critical.
5. `root: "rows"` property of `jsonReader` is default and can be removed. In the same way `shrinkToFit: true` option is default too (see the column "Default" in the table of option described in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options)) and can be removed.

Comment: The issue is the line: plugins/grid.addons.js. Removing this solved the problem.